# Read an open File Problem in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

hi
I have a program that log some data in text file in specific path.(log.txt)
I can open the file (log.txt) with notepad and read what is in it.

now I'm writing a program to read log.txt but I get the exception
"The process cannot access the file 'log.txt' because it is being used by another process."

what should I do?

Comment: have you closed stream of streamReader Class...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("log.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    // Actions you perform on the reader.
}
```

Whether you can open the file depends on the `FileShare` you've provided when opening the log file. The settings in the example above are quite low and maybe helps opening the file.

Comment: Yup, allowing FileShare.Write is the important one.  You can't deny write access, the program already acquired it.

Comment: I tried this solution but I used only FileShare.Read and it didn't wotk. Now I understand why I should use FileShare.ReadWrite.